# Deletar aquivos duplicados

Tags: python

Estou criando um script para varrer meu sistema e apagar todos os arquivos duplicados. Para não ter problemas na fase de teste troquei a função de apagar para copiar e estou testando em uma pasta específica, para ter certeza que está tudo ok, mas dá um erro que não sei resolver, e sempre reclama do último arquivo, não importa qual seja.

aparece isso:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):\Users\Unknown\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\filecmp.py", line 51, in cmp
    s1 = _sig(os.stat(f1))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado: '82110225_2471280396417255_4533531125607301120_n - Copia.jpg'
```

Esse é o código:

```
import os, shutil, filecmp,itertools

files = os.listdir('D:\\Scripts_Python\\Nova pasta\\')
extension =('.jpg')
for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith(extension):
        for f1, f2 in itertools.combinations(files,2):
            comp = filecmp.cmp(f1, f2,  shallow=False)
            if comp == True:
                shutil.copy(f2,'D:\\Scripts_Python\\Nova pasta\\Nova pasta\\')
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

Tudo indica que você não está usando o caminho completo do arquivo que você deseja copiar/apagar, a função `os.path.abspath()` pode ser usada para fazer essa "montagem".

Alternativamente, você pode usar a biblioteca `hashlib` para calcular a assinatura dos arquivos a fim de identificar os arquivos duplicados.

A assinatura calculada pode ser usada como a chave de um dicionário onde os valores seriam a lista de arquivos duplicados, veja só:

```
import os, hashlib

def duplicados( path, extension ):
    ret = {}

    # Para cada arquivo no diretorio
    for filename in os.listdir(path):

        # Somente arquivos com a extensão desejada
        if filename.endswith(extension):

            # Monta o caminho completo do arquivo
            fullpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, filename))

            # Calcula o hash MD5 (assinatura) do arquivo
            with open(fullpath,'rb') as f:
                md5sum = hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest()

            # Adiciona arquivo em um dicionario de listas
            # no qual a chave eh a assinatura do arquivo
            if md5sum not in ret:
                ret[md5sum] = []
            ret[md5sum].append(fullpath)

    # Filtra e retorna somente arquivos duplicados
    return { k:v for k, v in ret.items() if len(v) > 1 }

print(duplicados(path='D:\\Scripts_Python\\Nova pasta\\', extension='.jpg'))
```

**EDIT:**

Conforme sugestão dada nos comentários pelo colega `@jsbueno`, segue uma solução usando as bibliotecas `pathlib` e a `filecmp` capaz de solucionar o problema de forma mais eficiente:

```
from pathlib import Path
from filecmp import cmp as compare
from itertools import combinations
from networkx import Graph, connected_components

def duplicados( path, extension ):
    # Recupera lista de arquivos do diretorio
    # filtrados pela extensão
    files = [str(p) for p in Path(path).resolve().glob(extension)]

    # Recupera lista de pares duplicados
    dups = [(f1, f2) for f1, f2 in combinations(files,2) if compare(f1, f2)]

    # Constroi um grafo a partir dos
    # pares de arquivos duplicados
    grafo = Graph()
    grafo.add_edges_from(dups)

    # Retorna lista dos componentes
    # conectados do grafo (arquivos identicos)
    return list(connected_components(grafo))

print(duplicados(path='D:\\Scripts_Python\\Nova pasta\\', extension='*.jpg'))
```

Comment: eu também me preocupei em dar a dica da hashlib, para evitar que numa pasta com 30 imagens, o programa leia 900 arquivos - mas o filecmp do Python é esperto e já faz isso -  olha o help dele: "Return value: 
True if the files are the same, False otherwise.

This function uses a cache for past comparisons and the results,
with cache entries invalidated if their stat information
"

Comment: e também, não é legal indicar "os.pth.abspath"  a essa altura do campeonato - código desse tipo deve usar tudo o que for possível da "pathlib" - com  os métodos de "pathlib.Path"   - fica muito mais prático (e tudo no mesmo lugar) - o listdir, a checagem de extensão, até ler um arquivo   e o "stat" são métodos e properties de objetos  ` pathlib.Path`

Comment: @jsbueno: obrigado pelos comentários! segue edição.